# Background audio not work with Ionic3 + Videogular2 on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, audio-streaming, videogular

I'm using Videogular2 in an Angular/Cordova/Ionic3 project, where I play mp3 audio live streams. All works good with mp3 and mp4, on browser and iOS simulator.

When the user Lock The Screen in iOS Device I expect that the audio continues to play in a background mode, but on IOS when the user Lock The Screen audio stop to play.

I've tested on XCODE 8 to set 'Capabilities' tab adding 'audio' parameter, I've added cordova-plugin-backgroundaudio to the project without success.

On iOS Simulator it works well, the problem occurs only on iOS Device.
Tested on iPhone 6 & iPad 3.

I'm using:

- iOS 10.3.3
- XCODE 8.3.3
- Ionic 3.12.1
- Videogular2 5.4.11

No one else used videogular2 on cordova/ionic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS app audio won't be playing in background when the device is locked. For that you have to enable the background mode for the app. I had faced the same issue in one of my application (I was using different audio plugin).

In order to enable background mode in iOS you can use below plugin 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/. When you start playing the audio you just need to call backgroundMode.enable() to keep it playing in background. When you leave the audio player page if want you can disable background mode to avoid unnecessarily keeping the background mode on by calling backgroundMode.disable(). 
Additionally you need to enable the background audio feature in xcode project settings as shown in below link.

https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2016/09/BM-EnableAudioInBG.png

Comment: Thanks SAJ, but I did it, I've wrote about it in my question but I'm sorry for this misunderstanding :) however now I try to call backgroundMode.enable() inside the play() function, and I'll update you

Comment: "When you start playing the audio you just need to call backgroundMode.enable()" is the key! :-) If I call backgroundMode.enable() before api.play() it works. Before I called it in the app oninit and it has failed, thank you

Comment: Good catch, I unknowingly did it in the right way. My thought was if the user has not started playing the audio we don't need to unnecessarily enable background mode. Will keep this thing in mind for the future :) ..

Comment: I tried all what you suggested but I still have the same issue on ios11, is it working on your side for ios11 ?

Comment: No, I have not tested it on iOS 11 phones.

Comment: @Sathyajith When I call background enable on audio play, it plays that audio in background mode but it is not playing next audio. Did you face such issue?

Comment: @Darshana - Sorry, auto-playing the next track wasn't tried as it was not required for me.